# 404 (Not Found) for all Spring REST services in Angular web app

Tags: java, angularjs, maven, spring-mvc, jhipster

I am taking over an old colleague's code and he used JHipster to build a Maven-Spring-Angular project.

I am able to compile, package his code and I used a simple Chrome Web Server (plugin), point it at the project's "target" folder which contains all the web components (i.e. assets, bower_components, META-INF, WEB-INF, etc) and his code, a dashboard can run successfully on the Chrome Web Server.

Problem is, all API calls to the Java back-end are failing.

[IMAGE: API calls 404 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQSFG.png)

[IMAGE: Sample endpoint, api/data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCUoW.png)

Am I missing any steps when trying to run the project locally on my PC?

Comment: I think you have an issue with your ENDPOINT !! e.g. if Endpoint is /test/all we can call API using http://localhost:8080/test/all. 

can you provide exact API endpoint declared in your one of the Controller?

Comment: Added image of exact endpoint example, "/api/data".

Please bear with me as I am fairly new to Spring.

Comment: Okay then try invoking API using `localhost:8080/api/data/index`. Test it using REST client if possible so that you can test fast.

Comment: Tried that but it is not working, same as the error I got from the Chrome console. My root context is xxxdashboard and my Chrome Web Server is hosting /target/xxxdashboard folder. 

Not sure what is missing really...

Comment: I'm thinking is it because Chrome Web Server is not a Java servlet that's why the calls to the Spring backend cannot be made successfully?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Will update the answer in details soon but just want to share the solution.

Chrome Web Server is not a proper Servlet Container hence Spring wasn't able to start. Since Spring did not start, requests to the endpoints could not be handled.